# Initializing an array of string pairs without mentioning explicit type

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14

I'm trying to initialize an `std::array` of `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` but am unable to do it at the site of calling without explicitly including the `std::pair` type.

Here's the [complete executable code link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/EvquM6qet) and here are the relevant snippets:

Here are the aliases and declarations:

```
static constexpr size_t NUM_DATA = 3;
using DataPair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using Mapping = std::array<DataPair, NUM_DATA>;

static std::shared_ptr<Foo> create(Mapping&& list);

explicit Foo(Mapping&& pairs);
```

and here's the code at the calling site:

```
auto x= Foo::create({
    Foo::DataPair{"k1", "v1"}, 
    Foo::DataPair{"k2", "v2"}, 
    Foo::DataPair{"k3", "v3"}
});
// DOESN'T COMPILE!
// auto x= Foo::create({
//     {"k1", "v1"}, 
//     {"k2", "v2"}, 
//     {"k3", "v3"}
// });
```

I'm targeting C++14. I want to avoid passing in an `std::initializer_list` and *then* preparing an `std::array` out of it.

Comment: I would advise you not to use std::pair at all, unless you're inside some class template. In almost all other situations it is better to declare a struct of your own with two readable members. Such a struct also adds semantics making it harder to use parts of your code incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need another couple of curly-braces `{}` in there.

One pair for the `std::array` object, one pair for the array itself, and then a pair for each "pair" inside the array:

```
auto x= Foo::create({{
    {"k1", "v1"}, 
    {"k2", "v2"}, 
    {"k3", "v3"}
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [**`std::to_array`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array). The relevant part of example is exactly copied from the provided link:

```
auto a4 = std::to_array<std::pair<int, float>>(
        {{3, 0.0f}, {4, 0.1f}, {4, 0.1e23f}});
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid repeating the `std::pair<T,U>` while performing the conversion but nice suggestion nonetheless!

Comment: You'd need to define a template function with either a reference argument to built-in array (similar to `to_array` with fixed type) or make a variadic template bound on first type(like CTAD guide for std::array). I didn't want to get you into such complexities, but here you are.